# Trying to Output Battery CycleCount via Powershell on a single line

Tags: powershell, battery

The command I am using is the following:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\wmi'  -Class MSBatteryClass | select CycleCount
```

The output seems to be inconsistent and out puts multiple lines underneath CycleCount, is there a way to have the output be on a single line like so:

```
CycleCount: 0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the property with a oneliner:

`(Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\wmi'  -Class MSBatteryClass).CycleCount`

Output: `9`

If you want it to display exactly as you have written, then:

```
$cycles = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\wmi'  -Class MSBatteryClass).CycleCount
Write-host "CycleCount: $cycles"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.